# pyqt gui as an object of a main class rather than the main class itself. How do I connect callback to a method in the main class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

basically I have three classes:

1. MainClass
2. GUI
3. Foo

In this simple example MainClass should just execute some code in the class Foo whenever the button of the class GUI is pressed.

I know that a simple solution to this would be that you could use the GUI class itself as the main class and have the buttons callback function in the same class.
But I have so many functions, I want to seperate the GUI stuff and the code which should be executed when a GUI event occurs.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import sys 

class MainClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo = Foo()

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QMainWindow()
        ui = GUI()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        app.exec()
    
    def process_from_gui(self):
        #execute this when the button is clicked
        self.foo.bar()

class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        #do some stuff

class GUI():
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_callback)
        self.pushButton.setText("test button")
    
    def button_callback(self):
        pass
        #call method in MainClass

m = MainClass()
```

I hope I made myself clear and thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: When the button is clicked, I want a method from the main class to be executed

Comment: So would you just use the GUI as the main class?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you could do something like that

```
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class MainClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.foo = Foo()

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QMainWindow()
        ui = GUI()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow,self)
        MainWindow.show()
        app.exec()

    def process_from_gui(self):
        # execute this when the button is clicked
        self.foo.bar()


class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("something")


# do some stuff


class GUI():
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow,MainClass):
        self.MainWindow = MainClass
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_callback)
        self.pushButton.setText("test button")

    def button_callback(self, MainWindow):
        self.MainWindow.process_from_gui()  # your method in MainClass

if __name__=="__main__":
    m = MainClass()
```

Comment: Why would you use a partial function?

Comment: Of course you can also do this by storing the MainWindow as `self.MainWindow = MainWindow` as an attribute of Gui and then calling the function without partial and without it as a parameter. Partial was just the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @Mole it's actually unnecessary: you can just do `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.process_from_gui)`

Comment: @musicamante That would raise an attribute-error, since `MainWindow` is an instance of `QMainWindow`, and `process_from_gui` is an attribute of `MainClass`. (I don't think the OP is thinking clearly about how to separate the program logic from the gui, because the current code in `MainClass.__init__` is almost entirely gui-related).

Comment: @ekhumoro Right, but the issue is actually in the answer itself, as it would raise the same error in `button_callback`.

Comment: @Mole Now that I read again your answer, I can see that both your answers are not correct (as pointed out by ekhumoro). Also, remember that the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal always has a `checked` boolean argument: while you're not using the argument in the second code, the argument name is misleading.

Comment: Ah my bad, somehow i missread. I thought MainWindow is the name of the class declared above( MainClass ). My answer should work now, but  a connection on both sides is probably not a beautiful solution to this.